# Why is (n += 2 * i * i) faster than (n+= i) in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

This C++11 program takes on average between 7.42s and 7.79s to run.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using c = chrono::system_clock;
using s = chrono::duration<double>;

void func(){

    int n=0;
    const auto before = c::now();
    for(int i=0; i<2000000000; i++){
        n += i;
    }
    const s duration = c::now() - before;
    cout << duration.count();

}
```

if I replace `n += i` with `n += 2 * i * i` it takes between 5.80s and 5.96s. how come?

I ran each version of the program 20 times, alternating between the two. Here are the results:

```
n += i   |  n += 2 * i * i
---------+----------------
7.77047  |  5.87978
7.69226  |  5.83551
7.77375  |  5.84888
7.73748  |  5.84629
7.72988  |  5.84356
7.69736  |  5.83784
7.72597  |  5.84246
7.72722  |  5.81678
7.73291  |  5.81237
7.71871  |  5.81016
7.7478   |  5.80119
7.64906  |  5.80058
7.7253   |  5.9078
7.42734  |  5.96399
7.72573  |  5.84733
7.65591  |  5.81793
7.76619  |  5.83116
7.76963  |  5.84424
7.79928  |  5.87078
7.79274  |  5.84689
```

I have compiled it with (GCC) 9.1.1 20190503 (Red Hat 9.1.1-1). No optimization levels

> g++ -std=c++11

We know that the maximum integer is ~ 2 billion. So, when i ~ 32000, can we say that the compiler predicts that the calculation will overflow?

Comment: I was surprised that the compiler didn't optimize it. And indeed, with `-O2` they don't take any time at all.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations enabled? Which compiler did you use?

Comment: What compiler? Don't know for sure, but maybe the compiler spots that `n` is never used in the latter but not in the former?

Comment: I have a similar behavior with `g++ 7.4.0` (cygwin), no compiler options. I looked at decompiled code, and `2*i*i` has strictly more instructions (`imul    eax, eax` and `add     eax, eax`), so I guess some low-level stuff is happening (but I've no idea what exactly).

Comment: using gcc (GCC) 9.1.1 20190503 (Red Hat 9.1.1-1) on fedora 30. No compiler options.

Comment: @Adrian What? `+=` is used both times and nowhere else both times.

Comment: Firstly, performance with optimization disabled is meaningless. Secondly, both programs cause undefined behaviour due to integer overflow so all results are meaningless.  (And the compiler could hoist some or all of the loop out of between the timing checks)

Comment: I also suspect signed overflow... so UB.

Comment: As pointed out, you have to optimize for meaning. I get just a little faster, one try, with /02 ms142. See [this](https://pastebin.com/piDMwtGj)

Comment: Also, with something that runs that long, using an internal clock will be deceiving. VS comes with a tool called a profiler to clock running time. See [this](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/07-scheduling.html)

Comment: Can confirm on my machine (`gcc 7.4`, `core i5`). I can only suggest that this has to do with smth similar to branch prediction -- namely, at some point, your processor will predict that "every calculation from now will be overflow", so it will stop doing actual calculations. The 2nd version will come to this "undefined behaviour" point faster.

Comment: This is interesting, might do some analysis later.

Comment: @FalconUA did you look at your disassembly? I posted mine and there is no such check with ms142 /02. I can't imagine there is with gcc. Then again, if the op doesn't optimize... And he is not considering the long run time. mine was ~500ms.

Comment: Profiling without optimizations enabled results in irrelevant data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://godbolt.org/z/B3zIsv

You'll notice that with -O2, the code used to calculate 'n' is removed completely. So the real questions should be:

- Why are you profiling code *without* -O2?
- Why are you profiling code that has no observable side effects? *('n' can be removed completely - e.g. printing the value of 'n' at the end would be more useful here)*
- Why are you not profiling code in a profiler?

The timing results you have, result from a deeply flawed methodology.